# Print jobs held, and after manually releasing them, they return to being held.

Tags: printing, google

Everytime I try to print something, its status comes up as "held." When I try to release them, they go to "processing," and then back to "held." After a few times of releasing them, the jobs automatically abort.
I'm using a Konica Minolta MagiColor 1600w, connected via Google Cloud Print. (Using this program to connect: http://www.niftiestsoftware.com/cups-cloud-print/ )

Answer (score 3):

First thing to try:  change to a different version of the printer driver.  My HP Laserjet 3015 defaults to the postscript driver, which causes this behaviour.   Try the following:

- settings -> printers -> your printer -> properties
- "make and model" -> change
- select printer from database -> choose correct make
- in left column, choose correct model
- in right column, choose something other than the default.  I've had good luck with PCL3 and CUPS/Gutenprint.
- Good luck!

If that doesn't work, try to purge and reinstall cups.

- Remove cups completely with `apt-get remove cups --purge`.
- Back up and delete (or rename) your /etc/cups/ directory.
- Reinstall cups with `apt-get install cups`

Answer (score 1):

You can Install the printer driver for **Konica Minolta MagiColor** printers with :

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-m2300w
```